# How to sort characters in a string?

Tags: unix, command-line, sorting

I would like to sort the characters in a string.

E.g.

```
echo cba | sort-command
abc
```

Is there a command that will allow me to do this or will I have to write an `awk` script to iterate over the string and sort it?

Comment: Why can't this be done the way described above? Isn't sort able to take stdin as an input?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
echo cba | grep -o . | sort |tr -d "\n"
```

Comment: `grep -o .` is a cheap way to each character on its own line before using `sort`

Comment: Since this is already using grep, it's also easy to adjust to match only some characters. E.g. when you don't want to include whitespace in the result, `grep -o '\S'`.

Answer (score 16):

Please find the following useful methods:

**Shell**

Sort string based on its characters:

```
echo cba | grep -o . | sort | tr -d "\n"
```

String separated by spaces:

```
echo 'dd aa cc bb' | tr " " "\n" | sort | tr "\n" " "
```

**Perl**

```
print (join "", sort split //,$_)
```

**Ruby**

```
ruby -e 'puts "dd aa cc bb".split(/\s+/).sort'
```

**Bash**

With bash you have to enumerate each character from a string, in general something like:

```
str="dd aa cc bb";
for (( i = 0; i < ${#str[@]}; i++ )); do echo "${str[$i]}"; done
```

For sorting array, please check: [How to sort an array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)?

Answer (score 7):

This is cheating (because it uses Perl), but works. :-P

```
echo cba | perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = join "", sort split //'
```

Comment: or Ruby ;)

`echo cba | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.split(%r{\s*}).sort.join'`

Answer (score 6):

Another `perl` one-liner

```
$ echo cba | perl -F -lane 'print sort @F'
abc

$ # for reverse order
$ echo xyz | perl -F -lane 'print reverse sort @F'
zyx
$ # or
$ echo xyz | perl -F -lane 'print sort {$b cmp $a} @F'
zyx
```

- This will add newline to output as well, courtesy `-l` option

  - See [Command switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for doc on all the options
- The input is basically split character wise and saved in `@F` array
- Then sorted `@F` is printed

This will also work line wise for given input file

```
$ cat ip.txt 
idea
cold
spare
umbrella

$ perl -F -lane 'print sort @F' ip.txt 
adei
cdlo
aeprs
abellmru
```

Answer (score 0):

This would have been more appropriate as a comment to one of the `grep -o .` solutions (my reputation's not quite up to that low bar alas, damn my lurking), but I thought it worth mentioning that separating letters can be done more efficiently within the shell.  It's always worth avoiding code, but this *letsep* function is pretty small:

```
letsep ()
{
INWORD="$1"
while [ "$INWORD" ]
do
    echo ${INWORD:0:1}
    INWORD=${INWORD#?}
done
}
```

. . . and outputs one letter per line for an input string of arbitrary length.  For example, once *letsep* is defined, populating an array FLETRS with the letters of a string contained in variable FRED could be done (assuming contemporary *bash*) as:

```
readarray -t FLETRS < <(letsep $FRED)
```

. . . which for word-size strings runs about twice as fast as the equivalent :

```
readarray -t FLETRS < <(echo $FRED | grep -o .)
```

Whether this is worth setting up depends on the application. I've  only measured this crudely, but the slower procedural code seems to maintain an advantage over the context switch up to ~60 chars (*grep* is obviously more efficient, but loading it is relatively expensive). If the above operation is taking place in one or more steps of a loop over an indeterminate number of executions, the difference in efficiency can add up (at which point some might argue for switching tools and rewriting regardless, but that's another set of tradeoffs).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [@ghostdog74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376295/12638282) implemented in [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/):

```fish
string match --all --regex . "cba" | sort | string join ""
```