# sorting in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, sorting, csh

I have an array

```
arr=( x11 y12 x21 y22 x31 y32)
```

I need to sort this array to

```
x11 x21 x31 y12 y22 y32
```

So, I need to sort both alphabetical and numerical wise

How do I perform this in shell script ?

If I use `[ $i -le $j ]`, it says "integer expression expected".

And the strings may contain other characters also: `x.1.1` or `1.x.1`.

How do I do this ?

Comment: can u give me the complete syntax, I'm a beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First split the array elements into lines (most *nix programs work with lines only):

```
for el in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$el"
done
```

Then sort the lines:

```
for el in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$el"
done | sort
```

Now you can assign that to an array again:

```
arr2=( $(
    for el in "${arr[@]}"
    do
        echo "$el"
    done | sort) )
```

Bingo:

```
$ echo "${arr2[@]}"
x11 x21 x31 y12 y22 y32
```

To understand how all this works, and how to change it if it doesn't do *precisely* what you want, have a look at the `man` pages:

```
man bash
man sort
```

See also [How to sort an array in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash).

Comment: Can u give me the same syntax for a c shell. It says "Missing -" when run through cshell.

Comment: You should have specified that in the tags or the question. I don't know CSH.

Comment: But for numeric array, it will do lexicographic sort only. How can i sort numeric array then?