# How to find the highest number in an array?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)

I have numbers in the array `10 30 44 44 69 12 11...`. How to display the highest from array?

```
echo $NUM //result 69
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to follow the [rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) example.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `sort` to find out.

```
#! /bin/bash
ar=(10 30 44 44 69 12 11)
IFS=$'\n'
echo "${ar[*]}" | sort -nr | head -n1
```

Alternatively, search for the maximum yourself:

```
max=${ar[0]}
for n in "${ar[@]}" ; do
    ((n > max)) && max=$n
done
echo $max
```

Comment: Thank you very much
And if there was a string instead of numbers?

ar=("dsasd" "dsdas" "dasdsadaasdadadsadad")

Comment: @Charlie: Then you can use the string comparison `[[ $n > $max ]]`. Also, you can then remove the initialization of max.

Comment: Or maybe ar[0] if there's only one element...

Comment: @TNT: I don't understand your comment. I used `(( n > max ))` for numbers and recommended `[[ $n > $max ]]` for **strings**.

Comment: @choroba Sorry, didn't read carefully.

Comment: There's a problem with max=0 -- what if all args are negative?
Here's a better solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/40719447/2107205

Comment: @mato: fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
a=(10 30 44 44 69 12 11 100)

max=0
for v in ${a[@]}; do
    if (( $v > $max )); then max=$v; fi; 
done
echo $max
```

result in 100

Comment: Here's the same issue as in the answer above -- there's a problem with max=0 -- what if all args are negative? .. Here's a better solution -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40719447/2107205