# Sorting an array of mixed data

Tags: arrays, bash

Suppose that I have an array of such data:

```
arr[0] = "someText1 (x,y,z) a"
arr[1] = "someText2 (x,y,z) b"
```

How can I sort this array lexicographically [only taking the text into account] using Bash?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash

Comment: @Doppelganger: Did you just want to have the values of it through an output sorted and not actually how they are indexed in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Join on newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527049/bash-join-elements-of-an-array), pass to `sort`.

```
(IFS=$'\n'; sort <<<"${arr[*]}")
```

`sort <<<"fnord"` simply sends the string `"fnord"` as the standard input to `sort`; this is a Bash convenience notation for the clumsier `echo "fnord" | sort` (plus it avoids the extra process) and similarly, `sort <<<"${arr[*]}"` feeds the array to `sort`.

Because array pasting depends on the value of `IFS`, we change it to a newline so that `"${arr[*]}"` will result in a newline-separated list (the default `IFS` would cause the entries in the array to be expanded to a space-separated list).  In order to not change `IFS` permanently, we do this in a subshell; hence, the enclosing parentheses.

The [Bash manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is rather dense, but it's all there; or see the [Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: Can you please refer me to some documentation which will make me understand why this works?
Thanks!

Comment: Updated with a brief explanation.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to implement your own sorting algorithm; bubble-sort is pretty simple.

Another way is to use an external program, such as `sort`, to do your sorting. Here is a shell function that takes the array elements as arguments, and saves a sorted copy of the array into a variable named `$SORTED`:

```
function sort_array () {
    SORTED=()
    local elem
    while IFS= read -r -d '' elem ; do
        SORTED+=("$elem")
    done < <(printf '%s\0' "$@" | sort -z)
}
```

(Note the use of null bytes as a delimiter, rather than newlines, so that your array elements are unrestricted. This is achieved by the `-d ''` option to `read`, the `\0` in the `printf` format-string, and the `-z` option to `sort`.)

It can be used like this:

```
arr=('a b c' 'd e f' 'b c d' 'e f g' 'c d e')
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" # prints elements, one per line
sort_array "${arr[@]}"
arr=("${SORTED[@]}")
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" # same as above, but now it's sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in modules but you could just include the needed functions from the other file [array.sh](https://github.com/konsolebox/bash-library/blob/master/array.sh) to make it complete:

https://github.com/konsolebox/bash-library/blob/master/array/sort.sh

The function is customizable like producing elements or indices, and specializing on strings or integers. Just try to use it.

And one thing, it doesn't depend on external binaries like sort, and doesn't cause possible reinterpretation of data.