# Pick random from top 30% of int array

Tags: bash, random

Suppose I had a int array

```
array=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 )
```

How would I pick a random number from the top 30% of the array, numbers 8, 9, or 10.

I know to pick a number at complete random in the array is:

```
${array[RANDOM % ${#array[@]}]}
```

However I don't know how to do pick a random element in a percentage of the array,

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: Consider `size*.7 + (rand % size)*.3`. In this is case that would be `7 + (rand % size)/3`. (This can lead to bias, but I don't think it'll be an issue here anymore than rand % size in general.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Sort the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789688/1204143), in reverse:

   ```
   IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -rn <<<"${array[*]}"))
   ```
2. Figure out the number of eligible elements:

   ```
   n=$((${#sorted[@]}*3/10))
   ```
3. Pick a random element:

   ```
   val=${sorted[RANDOM % $n]}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Working off nneonneo's example...

So if I want to do something more dynamic I can do this:

```
percentage=0.3
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -rn <<<"${array[*]}"))
s=$(bc <<< $percentage*${#array[@]})
round=${s/.*}
round_ceil=$((round+1))
val=${sorted[RANDOM % $round_ceil]}
```

or do you see any bugs?

EDIT: I had to make a ceiling round instead of a floor round as floor rounds sometimes didn't produce a number.