# can't read no such variable while executing shell command inside expect script

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I have the code below. The goal is to

1. get the latest file which matches certain starting characters
2. to scp that file

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
ztools=$(ls -t|find -name '/home/user/releases/ztools*.tar.gz'|head -n1)
ztools=$(echo $ztools | cut -c 3-)

# connect via scp and transfer ztools
spawn scp /home/user/releases/${ztools} user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "Password\r"
}
}
interact
```

But when I run this I get the below error
can any one help me on this

```
can't read "(ls -t|find -name '/home/zadmin/releases/ztools*.tar.gz'|head -n1)":    no such variable
while executing
"ztools=$(ls -t|find -name '/home/zadmin/releases/ztools*.tar.gz'|head -n1)"
(file "copy_ztools_cust.sh" line 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have combined two scripts there. One shell script and one expect script.

This line is the shebang line for a shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

This line is the shebang line for an expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

These lines are shell code

```
ztools=$(ls -t|find -name '/home/user/releases/ztools*.tar.gz'|head -n1)
ztools=$(echo $ztools | cut -c 3-)
```

These lines are expect/tcl code

```
# connect via scp and transfer ztools
spawn scp /home/user/releases/${ztools} user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user
#######################
expect {
    -re ".*es.*o.*" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*sword.*" {
        exp_send "Password\r"
    }
}
interact
```

You need to split those lines back into separate bits of code if you expect this to work correctly.

Additionally those shell lines are not at all doing what you want and are not the proper way to go about that.

I don't believe that `ls -t` bit of the pipeline is doing anything for you as I don't believe find reads from standard input at all.

Do the `ztools*.tar.gz` filenames sort in a way that is useful to you or do you need to go by modification time of the file?

If the filenames sort alphabetically for you then what you want there is probably

```
ztools=(/home/zadmin/releases/ztools*.tar.gz)
ztools=${ztools[0]}
```

If the filenames don't sort alphabetically (but can be sorted using `sort`) then you probably want

```
ztools=$(printf '%s\0' /home/zadmin/releases/ztools*.tar.gz | sort -z)
ztools=${ztools[0]}
```

If the filenames can't be sorted using `sort` either and the modification times really are necessary then if your filenames are **guaranteed** to not contain any whitespace/newlines/glob metacharacters/etc. then you can use (but do note that this is not at all safe in the face of filenames that do)

```
ztools=$(ls -t | head -n1)
```

If you cannot be sure about the filenames you are going to deal with (and generally you shouldn't bet on it even if you believe you can) and modification times are still necessary then you are forced to use something more like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578277/258523).