# Rename files ordered by date

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I'm having trouble with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Digit new name (no spaces and special chars!): "
read newname

echo -e "\n"

i=0

if test "$(ls -A | grep [.]jpg)"; then
    for f in "$(ls -Atr | grep [.]jpg)"; do
        let i=i+1
        #mv "$f" "$(printf "${newname}_%03d.jpg" "$i")"
        echo "$f renamed in: " $(printf "${newname}_%03d.jpg" "$i")
    done
    echo -e "\n\033[1;33;41m$i substituded!\033[0m\a"
else
    echo -e "\n\033[1;33;41mNothing was done!\033[0m\a"
fi
sleep 3

exit
```

My problem is to substitute all file but ordered by date (older first).
On script above, I'm testing with `echo` and the result is all the list of files is renamed in one single files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're quoting `"$(ls -Atr | grep [.]jpg)"` so you're getting just a long string with all the filenames.

This would be a better attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Digit new name (no spaces and special chars!): " newname
echo
i=0
if test "$(ls -A | grep [.]jpg)"; then
    while IFS= read -r f; do
        let i=i+1
        #mv "$f" "$(printf "${newname}_%03d.jpg" "$i")"
        echo "$f renamed in: " $(printf "${newname}_%03d.jpg" "$i")
    done < <(ls -Atr | grep [.]jpg)
    echo -e "\n\033[1;33;41m$i substituded!\033[0m\a"
else
    echo -e "\n\033[1;33;41mNothing was done!\033[0m\a"
fi
```

---

Notice I'm using:

```
read -p "Digit new name (no spaces and special chars!): " newname
```

Instead of:

```
echo -n "Digit new name (no spaces and special chars!): "
read newname
```

`-p` option is for that purpose and output the text in the standard error.

---

#### Updated answer

Here an enhanced method **supporting also special chars**:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
read -p "Digit new name (no spaces and special chars!): " newname
echo
if test "$(ls -A | grep [.]jpg)"; then
    while read -r f; do
        ((i++))
        f=${f:1:((${#f}-2))} # remove the leading and trailing '
        f=${f//\\\"/\"}      # removed the \ before any embedded "
        f=$(echo -e "$f")    # interpret the escaped characters
        echo "$f renamed in: " $(printf "${newname}_%03d.jpg" "$i")
        #mv "$f" "$(printf "${newname}_%03d.jpg" "$i")"
        #file "$f"           # it's useful to test the script
    done < <(ls -Atr --quoting-style=c *.jpg .*.jpg)
else
    echo -e "\n\033[1;33;41mNothing was done!\033[0m\a"
fi
```

You can see a more explained answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036679/4095830).