# Loop through folder on files with filename having particular date

Tags: shell

I have to loop through all files in folder with particular date (say- 20150902) in the filenames.

I want to do this in shell script and take the date from the argument of the script.

I was using

for f in /data/test/loader/test01/XXX/$1*; do
commands
done

But it doesnt loop over all the filenames.

my filenames in folder look like this:

QQQ.XX8_XX2.FW00.20150902.0005399.30345.dat

and the date which is the input to the script is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through list of filenames in order they were created in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577074/iterate-through-list-of-filenames-in-order-they-were-created-in-bash)

Comment: @ryekayo - No i think i have date field in the middle of the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date is in the middle of your file name, so try `/data/test/loader/test01/XXX/*$1*` (note the asterisk added in front of $1).