# Sort list by number of character AND alphabetical

Tags: bash, sorting

Using bash I would like to sort a list of text strings in accordance with a first and a second order criteria:

1. Number of characters in the text string; string with fewest characters first
2. In order of the Danish alphabet which is the same as the English except for the letters `æ`, `ø`, `å` in the end (after `z`)

**Example:**

I would like this list:

```
aabb
ccc
aaaa
ddd
dgg
øøøø
aa
cc
ab
```

To be sorted into this:

```
aa
ab
cc
ccc
ddd
dgg
aaaa
aabb
øøøø
```

How can that be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: @MrCoder: No; this question has significant additional requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash, sort and cut:

```
while read -r l; do echo "${#l} $l"; done < filename | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Output:

```
aa
ab
cc
ccc
ddd
dgg
aaaa
aabb
øøøø
```

Comment: You need to use `read -r` and echo `"$l"` in double quotes, otherwise you will wreck input containing backslashes, runs of whitespace, glob characters, etc.

Comment: Without the appropriate locale, it is unlikely that words containing æ ø å will be sorted correctly.

Comment: In the very rare event that leading or trailing whitespace is important, `while IFS= read -r l` or `while read -r;` (when using the default variable `REPLY`, word-splitting is not applied to the value).

Comment: This sorting gets right with `LANG=da_DK.UTF-8` in `/etc/default/locale` (using Debian).

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
LC_SORT=da_DK perl -lpe 'print (len(), "\t")' input |
sort -k1n -k2,2 |
cut -f2- > output
```