# Linux bash scripting: sorting a list to use

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, scripting

I'm implementing a sort-function in my script, but I have trouble in doing so:

what I want to achieve is the following:

```
bash script --sort 44 55 1 23 44
```

output:

```
Pinging to 192.168.1.1 succes
Pinging to 192.168.1.23 failed
Pinging to 192.168.1.44 failed
Pinging to 192.168.1.55 failed
```

The pinging and stuff already works, I just don't know how to make a list with the arguments, sort them and (save the list) **then** use them in the ping command (by using `for var in $SORTEDLIST do <ping-command> done`.

I already had this:

```
    SORTEDLIST="$SORTEDLISTS $@"
    for var in $SORTEDLISTS
    do
            echo "$var"
    done | sort -n -u
```

The echo was just a test, but there I'll have to save the list somehow.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with `sort` before the `for` ?

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX The sort function needs something to sort on: it doesn't directly work on lists, so no, that won't do it. 

The echoed vars are now sorted, but I want to be able to put them in a sorted list.

Comment: is `$SORTEDLISTS` what is in output ?

Comment: @Kryptonous In my answer I suppose that you have just the last number of the IP, the one you provide on the command line. So you can sort it and complete later the full IP. Or maybe I misunderstood the problem and/or the context

Comment: No, @ColOfAbRiX, you're answer is correct as well. Pity I can only choose one solution! They're both really good. Actually, yours might even be slightly better in my situation. And indeed, I only use the last number of the IP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$@` is an array (of all script parameters), so you can sort using

```
OIFS="$IFS" # save IFS
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -n <<<"$*"))
IFS="$OIFS" # restore IFS
```

and then use the result like so:

```
for I in "${sorted[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Explanation:

- `IFS` is an internal shell variable ([internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)) which tells the shell which character separates words (default is space, tab and newline).
- `$'\n'` expands to a single newline. When the shell expands `$*`, it will now put a new line between each element.
- `sort -n <<<` pipes the "one argument per line" to `sort` which sorts numerically (`-n`)
- `sorted=($(...))` creates a new array with the result of the command `...`

See also:

- [How to sort an array in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: Should take a copy of IFS before changing it and change it back when done.

Comment: @User112638726: Like this?

Comment: Yep, always best to return things to how you found them!

Comment: Can I use this `"${sorted[@:1]"` to start from the 2nd argument?

Comment: The syntax is probably `"${sorted[@]:1}"`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68322/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-an-array-completely Or you can use `shift` before the assignment of `sorted` to remove the first element from `$*`

Answer (score 1):

This script takes the command line arguments, it splits them one per line `tr ' ' '\n'`, sort them numerically `tr ' ' '\n'` and print them :

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST="$@"

for I in $(echo "$LIST" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -g)
do
    echo $I
    echo "192.168.0.1.$I"
done
```