# How can I sort the string array in linux bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For instance, the array is

```
link2_pathname
link1_pathname
link3_pathname
```

How can I get the array like below.

```
link1_pathname
link2_pathname
link3_pathname
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash

Answer (score 5):

pipe a loop to `sort`.

```
a=(l2 l3 l1)
b=($(for l in ${a[@]}; do echo $l; done | sort))
```

you probably need to watch out for the IFS when handling string values containing spaces.

Comment: thanks. I tested this script,  why it output l2 when I echo $a. I want to output l2,l3,l1

Comment: i do not know bash's inner handling of the IFS when printing an array. `@` or `*` expand to all entries in an array.  you might want to access or print the values contained by `echo ${a[@]}`. ${a} probably just returns l2 because the default IFS, which is a space is recocognized and therefor cut off due to uncomplete variable expansion.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var=( link2_pathname link1_pathname link3_pathname )

for arr in "${var[@]}"
do
    echo $arr
done | sort

new_var=( $(for arr in "${var[@]}" 
do
        echo $arr
done | sort) )
```