# Sort multiple column String array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sorting

I have an array of strings:

```
arr[0]="1 10 2Z6UVU6h"
arr[1]="1 12 7YzF5mFs"
arr[2]="2 36 qRwAiLg7"
```

How could i sort by the 2nd column and use the 1st as a tie break.

Is there anything similar to something like...

```
sort -k 2,2n -k 1,1 $arr
```

Comment: Here are some examples: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash) instead of just `sort` use `sort -k2 -k1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are no newline characters in any array element, it's straight-forward: Just printf the array into sort and capture the output:

```
mapfile -t sorted < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -k2,2n -k1,1)
```

(The use of process substitution is to avoid having the mapfile run in a subshell, which wouldn't be helpful since the goal is to set the value of `$sorted` in this shell.)

If the array elements might contain newlines, then you could use NUL as a delimiter in the `printf` and the `sort` (option `-z` for sort), but you'd have to replace `mapfile` with an explicit loop because `mapfile` does not offer an option to change the line delimiter. `read` does (`-d ''` will cause `read` to use NUL as a line delimiter), but it only reads one line at a time.