# sort multiple line record with awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a file with records looking like this:

```
nad9
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1393     1,196   abie_by_ctai_prots_1_196
   abie_by_wmir_prots   contig_4729                         811,  1363     2,187   abie_by_wmir_prots_2_187
   abie_by_gbil_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1393     1,196   abie_by_gbil_prots_1_196
   abie_by_atha_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1363     1,186   abie_by_atha_prots_1_186

ND2
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_1280                        9618, 11661     0,182   abie_by_ctai_prots_0_182
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_9528                         770,   959   427,490   abie_by_ctai_prots_427_490
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_6628                        5874,  2217   182,429   abie_by_ctai_prots_182_429

ccmB
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_334                        39851, 39218     0,212   abie_by_ctai_prots_0_212
   abie_by_wmir_prots   contig_334                        39842, 39218     2,211   abie_by_wmir_prots_2_211
   abie_by_gbil_prots   contig_334                        39851, 39218     0,212
```

I want to sort the records based on the gene names (first line of record). 
The output should look like this:

```
ND2
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_1280                        9618, 11661     0,182   abie_by_ctai_prots_0_182
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_9528                         770,   959   427,490   abie_by_ctai_prots_427_490
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_6628                        5874,  2217   182,429   abie_by_ctai_prots_182_429

ccmB
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_334                        39851, 39218     0,212   abie_by_ctai_prots_0_212
   abie_by_wmir_prots   contig_334                        39842, 39218     2,211   abie_by_wmir_prots_2_211
   abie_by_gbil_prots   contig_334                        39851, 39218     0,212   abie_by_gbil_prots_0_212

nad9
   abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1393     1,196   abie_by_ctai_prots_1_196
   abie_by_wmir_prots   contig_4729                         811,  1363     2,187   abie_by_wmir_prots_2_187
   abie_by_gbil_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1393     1,196   abie_by_gbil_prots_1_196
   abie_by_atha_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1363     1,186   abie_by_atha_prots_1_186
```

I have tried this code without success:
`vilde$ awk '{ RS = ""; FS = "\n"} {print $0}' |sort filename.txt`

It gives me output looking similar to this:

```
(empty line)    
(empty line)
(empty line)  
abie_by_ctai_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1393     1,196   abie_by_ctai_prots_1_196
abie_by_wmir_prots   contig_4729                         811,  1363     2,187   abie_by_wmir_prots_2_187
abie_by_gbil_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1393     1,196   abie_by_gbil_prots_1_196
abie_by_atha_prots   contig_4729                         808,  1363     1,186   abie_by_atha_prots_1_186
ND2   
ccmB
nad9
```

Seems to me that it is sorting on fields instead of records, but I don't understand why or how to change this.

Comment: `sort` sorts lines. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `awk` here.

Comment: Im a complete nob to this so I might be approaching this the wrong way. Could I possibly replace all new lines temporarily to get each record on one line. this way I can use sort?

Comment: If the input isn't too big, I'd just do something like `perl -00 -e 'print sort readline'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this :

**A small file:**
If you want to sort a small file, you can use GNU awk for this and make use of `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` which will give you array traversal in ascending index order.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS="\n"
           PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" }
     {a[$1]=$0}
     END{for(i in a) { print a[i] } }' <inputfile> > <outputfile>
```

**A humongous file:** If you want to do this with a very big file, then awk will choke on it, so you have to do it a bit different with some `awk`, `sort` and `cat` stuff. The idea is to create a lot of files with the correct name and then sort the files and cat them :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inputfile=$1
outputfile=$2

dir=$(mktemp -d)
awk -v dir=$dir 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS="[[:blank:]]*\n"}
     { fname=dir"/"$1; print $0 > fname; close(fname) }' $inputfile
export LC_ALL=C
files=( $dir/* )
sort <<< ${files[*]} | xargs cat > $outputfil
rm -rf $dir
```

or you can just use a single big pipe-line :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";OFS="|"}{gsub(FS,OFS)}1' <inputfile> | sort \
   | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n";OFS="\n";FS="\\|"}{gsub(FS,OFS)}1' > <outputfile>
```

**note:** I assume there are no Windows `\r\n` in your file. Your original input shows that this is the case.

**Useful links:**

- [What's the default order of Linux sort?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43465/whats-the-default-order-of-linux-sort)
- [How to sort an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: Thank you! I tried both and it worked perfectly with a small file. However for my complete file I get the error : cat: rps19: No such file or directory
cat: rps2: No such file or directory
cat: rps3: No such file or directory
cat: rps4: No such file or directory

Comment: Thank you! The single pipe-line worked for the big file.

Answer (score 1):

Your command line in your question appears to provide no input to the `awk` command, so you're simply sorting the individual lines of your input file. But you're on the right track with `RS=""`.

Most sort implementations, as far as I'm aware, won't handle multiple line input for individual records. But your records look like the kind of thing that `awk` would process nicely, so I think my approach would be to use a pipeline to convert newlines within the records to allow records to be sorted, then convert them back after the sort. Like this:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/,"#")} 1' input.txt | sort | awk '{gsub(/#/,"\n")} 1'
```

Note that this does not place blank lines between records. If you need those, replace the final `1` with: `{print $0 ORS}`.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a text file (eg, there are no null bytes in it), you can do some pre/post-processing.  My perl is a little rusty, but here's a simple way to replace each of the newlines within a record with a null byte, then use sort, then put back in the newlines.

```
perl -e 'while(<>){ chop; $p .=  ($_ eq "") ? "\n" : "\000" ; 
    print $p; $p=$_; }' input.txt | sort | perl -pe 's/\000/\n/g'
```

Perhaps a little cleaner to write it as:

```
< input.txt perl -000 -lape 's/\n/\000/g' | 
    sed '/^$/d' | sort | 
    perl -ne 's/\000/\n/g; print $_ . "\n"'
```

Using paragraph slurping (rather than slurping the whole file) is a pointless attempt to enable large files by not putting everything in  memory.  (Pointless, because if the problem is that the size of data will be enough to cause problems, then `sort` is going to choke.)