# How to print numbers in ascending & descending order using for loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have some numbers, and I want to print those numbers in ascending and descending order using a for loop. Please find the example for loop only which I am providing.

1. Ascending order.

   ```
   for i in 10 -29 33 67 -6 7 -10; do
       echo ("Printing the numbers in ascending order: $i")
   done
   ```
2. descending order.

   ```
   for i in 10 -29 33 67 -6 7 -10; do
       echo ("Printing the numbers in descending order: $i")
   done
   ```

Comment: You can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash

Comment: To sort numbers you need to "see" them all at the same time. So it's not possible to do it "in a loop" - you need to load all the numbers, sort them, and then output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bubble algorithm to sort an array :

### Descending order

```
numbers=(10 -29 33 67 -6 7 -10)

for (( i=0 ; i < ${#numbers[@]}; i++ )) 
do
    for (( j=0 ; j < ${#numbers[@]}; j++ )) 
    do
      if [[ ${numbers[$j]} -lt  ${numbers[$i]} ]]
      then
        tmp=${numbers[$i]}
        numbers[$i]=${numbers[$j]}
        numbers[$j]=${tmp}
      fi
    done
done

for n in "${numbers[@]}"
do
    echo "$n"
done
```

### Ascending order

```
numbers=(10 -29 33 67 -6 7 -10)

for (( i=0 ; i < ${#numbers[@]}; i++ )) 
do
    for (( j=0 ; j < ${#numbers[@]}; j++ )) 
    do
      if [[ ${numbers[$j]} -gt  ${numbers[$i]} ]]
      then
        tmp=${numbers[$i]}
        numbers[$i]=${numbers[$j]}
        numbers[$j]=${tmp}
      fi
    done
done

for n in "${numbers[@]}"
do
    echo "$n"
done
```

Or you can cheat and use sort :

### Descending order

```
for i in $( echo "10 -29 33 67 -6 7 -10" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nr )
do
  echo $i
done
```

### Ascending order

```
for i in $( echo "10 -29 33 67 -6 7 -10" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -r )
do
  echo $i
done
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this approach doesn't seem to be fair, but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch list.txt
for i in 29 -12 3 44; do
  echo $i >> list.txt
done

while read LINE; do
  echo $LINE
done < <(sort -n list.txt)
rm list.txt
```

Comment: Instead of using a temporary file, you could redirect the entire loop: `for i in 29 -12 3 44; do echo "$i"; done | sort -n`