# How to sort the characters of a word using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I can't seem to find any way of sorting a word based on its characters in awk.
For example if the word is "hello" then its sorted equivalent is "ehllo". how to achieve this in awk ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Awk is not strong on sorting and even less so within a string. Why have you chosen awk? If that isn't a hard requirement - you are better served using another tool.

Comment: I have started learning shell scripting a few days ago, can you recommend the tool to sort a string ? I have to check if a particular string is a permutation of another string. I thought of sorting both and then comparing letter by letter, but could not find anything to sort the string.

Comment: For non-awk based solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373874/how-to-sort-characters-in-a-string

Comment: This site exists to help people with their code. [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus your attempt to solve the problem yourself and then we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk for `PROCINFO[]`, "sorted_in" (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) and splitting with a null separator resulting in an array of chars:

```
$ echo 'hello' |
awk '
    BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc" }
    {
        split($1,chars,"")
        word = ""
        for (i in chars) {
            word = word chars[i]
        }
        print word
    }
'
ehllo
```

```
$ echo 'hello' | awk -v ordr='@val_str_asc' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]=ordr} {split($1,chars,""); word=""; for (i in chars) word=word chars[i]; print word}'
ehllo
```

```
$ echo 'hello' | awk -v ordr='@val_str_desc' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]=ordr} {split($1,chars,""); word=""; for (i in chars) word=word chars[i]; print word}'
ollhe
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is a *Decorate-Sort-Undecorate* with `sed`. Essentially, you use `sed` to break `"hello"` into one character per-line (decorating each character with a newline `'\n'`) and pipe the result to `sort`. You then use `sed` to do the reverse (undecorate each line by removing the `'\n'`) to join the lines back together.

```
printf "hello" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | sed '{:a N;s/\n//;ta}'
ehllo
```

There are several approaches you can use, but this one is shell friendly, but the behavior requires GNU `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be more doable with gawk, which includes the `asort` function to sort an array:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=ORS=""}{split($0,a);asort(a);for(i in a)print a[i]}'<<<hello
```

This outputs:

```
ehllo
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/ylWQLJ

Comment: This is wrong, idk why it's the accepted answer. I guess maybe it produced the expected output for some sample input and the OP thought that it'd always do that but it won't - if that happened it was just luck.

Comment: @EdMorton Hi, thanks for your insight. Could you please tell why it would fail ?

Comment: @Abhi `for(i in a)` by default visits the array indices in implementation-dependent (often hash) order (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array) so you can have input like `bca` then run `asort()` and it becomes `abc` then run `for (i in a)` and get output of `cab` or `bca` or `acb` or anything else. Even if you get the output you want now, you can get output you don't want for other input or for a different version of the tool or when run on a different platform or.....

Comment: @EdMorton I get your point now. Thanks for the clarification. I read the link that you had provided and for `gawk`, I found that it can forced to iterate in numeric order by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`. Though I don't exactly know how to do it here.

Comment: @Abhi I already provided an answer that does exactly that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69192721/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a function to sort letters in a word (see : https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html):

```
function siw(word,        result, arr, arrlen, arridx) {
    split(word, arr, "")
    arrlen = asort(arr)
    for (arridx = 1; arridx <= arrlen; arridx++) {
        result = result arr[arridx]
    }
    return result
}
```

And define a sort sub-function to compare two words (see : https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html):

```
function compare_by_letters(i1, v1, i2, v2,        left, right) {
    left  = siw(v1)
    right = siw(v2)
    if (left < right)
        return -1
    else if (left == right)
        return 0
    else
        return 1
}
```

And use this function with awk sort function:

```
asort(array_test, array_test_result, "compare_by_letters")
```

Then, the sample program is:

```
function siw(word,        result, arr, arrlen, arridx) {
    result = hash_word[word]
    if (result != "") {
        return result
    }
    split(word, arr, "")
    arrlen = asort(arr)
    for (arridx = 1; arridx <= arrlen; arridx++) {
        result = result arr[arridx]
    }
    hash_word[word] = result
    return result
}

function compare_by_letters(i1, v1, i2, v2,        left, right) {
    left  = siw(v1)
    right = siw(v2)
    if (left < right)
        return -1
    else if (left == right)
        return 0
    else
        return 1
}

{
    array_test[i++] = $0
}

END {
    alen = asort(array_test, array_test_result, "compare_by_letters")
    for (aind = 1; aind <= alen; aind++) {
        print array_test_result[aind]
    }
}
```

Executed like this:

```sh
echo -e "fail\nhello\nborn" | awk -f sort_letter.awk
```

Output:

```
fail
born
hello
```

Of course, if you have a big input, you could adapt `siw` function to memorize result for fastest compute:

```
function siw(word,        result, arr, arrlen, arridx) {
    result = hash_word[word]
    if (result != "") {
        return result
    }
    split(word, arr, "")
    arrlen = asort(arr)
    for (arridx = 1; arridx <= arrlen; arridx++) {
        result = result arr[arridx]
    }
    hash_word[word] = result
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a *very* unorthodox method for a quick-n-dirty approach, if you really want to sort "hello" into "ehllo" :

```
mawk/mawk2/gawk 'BEGIN { FS="^$" 

        # to make it AaBbCc… etc;  chr(65) = ascii "A"

        for (x = 65; x < 91; x++) {

            ref = sprintf("%s%c%c",ref, x, x+32) 

   } } /^[[:alpha:]]$/ { print } /[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]+/ { 
   
             # for gawk/nawk, feel free to change 
             # that to /[[:alpha:]]{2,}/
             # the >= 2+ condition is to prevent wasting time
             # sorting single letter words "A" and "I"

      s=""; x=1; len=length(inp=$0);

      while ( len && (x<53) ) {  
         if (inp~(ch = substr(ref,x++,1))) {
            while ( sub(ch,"",inp) ) {
                   s  = s ch; 
                 len -= 1   ;
      } } }

    print s }'
```

I'm aware it's an extremely inefficient way of doing selection sort. The potential time-savings stem from instant loop ending the moment all letters are completed, instead of iterating all 52 letters everytime. The downside is that it doesn't pre-profile the input

(e.g. if u detect that this row is only lower-case, then u can speed it up with a lowercase only loop instead)

The upside is that it eliminates the need for custom-functions, eliminate any gawk dependencies, and also eliminate the need to split every row into an array (or every character into its own field)

i mean yes technically one can set FS to null string thus automatically becomes having NF as the string length. But at times it could be slow if input is a bit large. If you need unicode support, then a `match()`-based approach is more desirable.

- added (x<53) condition to prevent run-away infinite loops in case input isn't pure ASCII letters